# jstl and eclipse: maybe EL issue

Tags: jstl, eclipse-indigo

I'm using tomcat 7.0.26 and indigo eclipse.

I put the jstl jars in my webapp `WEB-INF/lib` how it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). I put jstl-api-1.2.jar and jstl-impl-1.2.jar.

In my webapp `web.xml`, I have:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

In my .jsp file, I have

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

I have some warnings in my .jsp file on:

```
  <form> 
        <select id="language" name="language" onchange="submit()">
            <option value="en" ${language == 'en' ? 'selected' : ''}>English</option>
            <option value="it" ${language == 'it' ? 'selected' : ''}>Italian</option> 
        </select> 
    </form>
```

Precisely:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Invalid location of text (''}) in tag 
 (<option>).
- Invalid location of text (') in tag 
 (<option>).
- Undefined attribute name (en).
- Undefined attribute name (language).
- Invalid location of text (${) in tag 
 (<option>).
- Undefined attribute name (:).
- Invalid location of text (' ? ') in tag 
 (<option>).
```

In "Console", this warning appears:

```
At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

My simple app doen't succeed in displaying the right labels according to the user language.

Could the option-tag/EL warning depend on jstl file jars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form> 
    <select id="language" name="language" onchange="submit()">
        <option value="en" <c:out value="${language == 'en' ? 'selected' : ''}"/> >English</option>
        <option value="it" <c:out value="${language == 'it' ? 'selected' : ''}"/> >Italian</option> 
    </select> 
</form>
```